# MySQL Syntax Error (Ubuntu LAMP Server)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lamp

Alright, so I've got a fairly fresh Ubuntu (server) installation. Just finished installing the LAMP server and when I go to create a database I'm getting the generic syntax error (1064 / 42000).

My query:

```
CREATE DATABASE phpbb;
```

Pretty simple and pretty standard, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Any ideas?

Comment: 1064 usually comes with a contextual message indicating an error near some character. Did you not get one?

Comment: can you check whats on the mysql.log

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u mike -p
CREATE DATABASE phpbb' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks from your error like you're trying to execute SQL on the command line, something like:

```
mysql -u mike -p CREATE DATABASE phpbb';
```

MySQL isn't going to like that, it separates the initiation of the tool from the SQL commands.

What I'd normally do for CREATE DATABASE, as it's a one off, I'd do it manually.

So start the tool with

mysql -u mike -p

This should prompt you for your password, and connect to the local database, giving you a shell prompt:

```
mysql>
```

You then issue your

```
CREATE DATABASE phpbb;
```

If you want to run scripts from the command line, put them in a file and redirect the input to mysql.  Usually you'd redirect the output too - something like this:

```
mysql -u mike -p < mysqlscript.sql  > outputofscript.log
```